# Getting data from MYI, MYD, frm files

Tags: mysql, myisam

I have a folder with files of the format: MYI, MYD, frm. I need to access these files somehow. I tried to create a db, and transfer files there with the user mysql and with the rights of a neighboring running database, restarted the mysql server, but muskl does not see these tables. I am not experienced in solving such problems, I will be grateful for any help.
I know that this is not the correct database format, but I was given this data and there are no others
sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to solve through the mysql-server 5.7+. The database is relatively old and not readable in 8.0+
Who faced such a problem, in order not to install the base, try through the docker and the necessary mysql-server